# Override PerfomClick Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

Im trying to get a drawableLeft cross icon in a editText, to clean it, but I dont know how to override the perfomClick() method on kotlin language, because it seems that kotlin doesn't recognizes perfomclick. Here is my override code for the onTouch event.

```
override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            super.onTouchEvent(event)

            when(event.action){
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    Log.i("TAg", "Action Up")
                    et_email.performClick()
                    if(event.getRawX() >= (et_email.getRight() - et_email.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width())) {
                        et_email.setText("")
                        Log.i("TAg", "Action Up")
                        return true
                    }
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    Log.i("TAg", "Action Down")
                    et_email.performClick()
                    return true
                }
            }

            return false
        }
```

The warning appears inside onCreate method, when I call the setOnTouchListener like this.

```
et_email.setOnTouchListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override `perfomClick()`, use:

```
override fun performClick(): Boolean {
    super.performClick()
    // your logic here
    return true // or return false, if you like
}
```